# Epson L6160 Printer Stopped Working

Tags: drivers, 18.04

Please I have been struggling for more than a week. Got the new Epson L6160 printer to work but it stopped working and I am very frustrated. Epson L6160 printer driver for Ubuntu 18.4 needed. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can try the drivers from this page:

https://www.epson.com.sg/Support/Printers/Ink-Tank-Printers/L-Series/Epson-L6160/s/SPT_C11CG21502?review-filter=Linux